# What causes "Illegal start of expression" errors?

Tags: java, compilation

I am mostly getting illegal starts to expressions and semicolons expected before the curly braces in my methods. I really need some help with this as I can't for the life of me figure out why I'm getting so many errors

```
public class stockItem{

    //Declaring Variables
    private double price;
    private  boolean delivery;
    private static int counter = 0;
    // New array with all the catagories stored in it
    private String[] catagoryArray = new String[] {"furniture", "silver", "mirrors", "jewelry", "miscellaneous"};
    private String Catagory;
    private String code;

    //default constructor for stockItem
    public stockItem(){
        price = 0;
        Catagory = catagoryArray[0];
        delivery = false;
        counter++;
        code = "default";
    }

    // Constructor for stockItem made by the user with all nessacey inputs
        public stockItem(String Catagory, double price, boolean delivery){
            for (int i =0; i < catagoryArray.length; i++){
                if (Catagory.equalsIgnoreCase(catagoryArray[i])){
                    this.Catagory = catagoryArray[i];
            } else {
                System.out.println("This is not a valid catagory!");
            }
            // Variables overwrite old variables from default stockItem
            this.price = price;
            this.delivery = delivery;
            counter++;
            code = code();
        }

        // Generates codes for each catagory and each item created
        private String getCode(){
            String furnCode = catagoryArray[0].substring(0,4) + counter;
            String silverCode = catagoryArray[1].substring(0,4) + counter;
            String mirrorsCode = catagoryArray[2].substring(0,4) + counter;
            String jewelry = catagoryArray[3].substring(0,4) + counter;
            String miscCode = catagoryArray[4].substring(0,4) + counter;
        }

        //Methods

        //Returns price of an object
        public double getPrice(){
            return price;
        }

        //Returns true of false for delivery of an object
        public boolean getDelivery(){
                return delivery;
        }

        //Returns the counter value
        public int getCounter(){
                return counter;
        }

        // Returns the catagory of an object
        public String getCatagory(){
                return Catagory;
        }

        // gets code of particular item
        public String getCode(){
                return code;
        }

        // Returns the amount of objects created
        public int objectAmount(){
            return counter;
        }

        //changes price of an object when called
        public void changePrice(double Price){
                this.price = Price;
        }

        // changes delivery option
        public void changeDelivery(boolean changeDelivery){
            this.delivery = changeDelivery;
        }

        // Changes catagory of an object
        public void changeCatagory(String changeCatagory){
            this.Catagory = changeCatagory;
        }

        //Prints a string containing all information about an object
        public String changeToString(){
            String Print = "Catagory:" + Catagory + "Price:" + price + "Amount Created" + counter + "Code" + code;
            return Print;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're missing a closing brace for your for loop.

Comment: You might want to use some IDE ( eclipse ?) .. it will help find the issue easily ..

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't look right :

```
code = code(); // where is code() defined?
```

Your `getCode()` method also doesn't look right, since it has a return value but returns nothing.

Finally :

```
//Prints a string containing all information about an object
public String changeToString(){
    String Print = "Catagory:" + Catagory + "Price:" + price + "Amount Created" + counter + "Code" + code;
    return Print;
    } // this should be removed
}
```

Comment: why should that curly brace be removed on the changeToString() method? and my get code is supposed to return the value of code for a specific object, how can i fix that?

Comment: @Tomwozzer What does it close? If you want `getCode()` to return something. add `return ...` at the end of that method.

Comment: i assumed i had to put it at the end to let the compiler know its the end of my code, if i take it out the compiler tells me "error: reached end of file while parsing" and for the get code method i am returning code thats is already in my code did you not see that?

Comment: @Tomwozzer You need one "}" at the end of the last method and another one for the end of the class, but you have 3.

Comment: okay i have sorted that, i am down to one error now it says this when i try to compile...
"stockItem.java:75: error: method getCode() is already defined in class stockItem
  public String getCode(){ 
                ^

Comment: @Tomwozzer You do have two `getCode()` methods. Rename one of them

Comment: i done this now i have this error "stockItem.java:50: error: missing return statement"

Comment: @Tomwozzer I already told you in my answer, your `getCode()` method (at least the first one) should return a String, since it's declared to return a String.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the things pointed out by Eran there is also an unmatched curly brace in stockItems. The for loop is missing a final brace.

```
public stockItem(String Catagory, double price, boolean delivery){
    for (int i =0; i < catagoryArray.length; i++){
        if (Catagory.equalsIgnoreCase(catagoryArray[i])){
            this.Catagory = catagoryArray[i];
        } else {
            System.out.println("This is not a valid catagory!");
        }

    } // This one.

    // Variables overwrite old variables from default stockItem
    // ... code ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a valid code. Few things to point out:

1. You should name a class StockItem, not stockItem. Read about Java naming convention.
2. You have tvo getCode() methods. Can't do that. I renamed one of them to getCode1(). Choose a name you like. And this method should return a String.
3. Missing closing bracket in constructor. I added some, bot not sure it's the right position.

As someone mentioned, you should consider using some IDE.

```
public class StockItem {

    //Declaring Variables
    private double price;
    private boolean delivery;
    private static int counter = 0;
    // New array with all the catagories stored in it
    private String[] catagoryArray = new String[] {"furniture", "silver", "mirrors", "jewelry", "miscellaneous"};
    private String Catagory;
    private String code;

    //default constructor for StockItem
    public StockItem() {
        price = 0;
        Catagory = catagoryArray[0];
        delivery = false;
        counter++;
        code = "default";
    }

    // Constructor for StockItem made by the user with all nessacey inputs
    public StockItem(String Catagory, double price, boolean delivery) {
        for (int i = 0; i < catagoryArray.length; i++) {
            if (Catagory.equalsIgnoreCase(catagoryArray[i])) {
                this.Catagory = catagoryArray[i];
            } else {
                System.out.println("This is not a valid catagory!");
            }
        } // not sure if the closing bracket should be here
        // Variables overwrite old variables from default StockItem
        this.price = price;
        this.delivery = delivery;
        counter++;
        code = getCode();
    }

    // Generates codes for each catagory and each item created
    private String getCode1() {
        String furnCode = catagoryArray[0].substring(0, 4) + counter;
        String silverCode = catagoryArray[1].substring(0, 4) + counter;
        String mirrorsCode = catagoryArray[2].substring(0, 4) + counter;
        String jewelry = catagoryArray[3].substring(0, 4) + counter;
        String miscCode = catagoryArray[4].substring(0, 4) + counter;
        return ""; // this method should return a string!
    }

    //Methods

    //Returns price of an object
    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    //Returns true of false for delivery of an object
    public boolean getDelivery() {
        return delivery;
    }

    //Returns the counter value
    public int getCounter() {
        return counter;
    }

    // Returns the catagory of an object
    public String getCatagory() {
        return Catagory;
    }

    // gets code of particular item
    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    // Returns the amount of objects created
    public int objectAmount() {
        return counter;
    }

    //changes price of an object when called
    public void changePrice(double Price) {
        this.price = Price;
    }

    // changes delivery option
    public void changeDelivery(boolean changeDelivery) {
        this.delivery = changeDelivery;
    }

    // Changes catagory of an object
    public void changeCatagory(String changeCatagory) {
        this.Catagory = changeCatagory;
    }

    //Prints a string containing all information about an object
    public String changeToString() {
        String Print = "Catagory:" + Catagory + "Price:" + price + "Amount Created" + counter + "Code" + code;
        return Print;
    }

}
```